# Excel VBA formula with a variable

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a code that is hard coded for a range, I'd like it to be universal. I have a Variable called "LastLine" which works well for when I'm setting a range to set a formula IE:

```
Range("A1:A" & Lastline).FormulaR1C1 = "..."
```

but When I try to use it in the formula itself I'm doing something wrong

```
Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R3C8:R & Lastline & C8)"
```

can someone explain how I'm doing this wrong and if so is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You don't want the literal string to appear so remove from inside the quotes `range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R3C8:R" & Lastline & "C8)"`

Comment: Thank you could you submit an Answer please

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the actual `Lastline` literal, but its value. So you need to use something like

`Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R3C8:R" & Lastline & "C8)"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite understanding the intention, but as far as syntax goes you need to slightly amend the string:

```
Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R3C8:R" & Lastline & "C8)"
```